# What is the decomposition of of 120 and 128 reps of $SO(16)$ under $SO(12)\times SO(4)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

$E_8\supset SO(16)$

$248=120+128$

What is the decomposition of of 120 and 128 reps of $SO(16)$ under $SO(12)\times SO(4)$?

Comment: Is it clear that there are unique (irreducible) representations of those dimensions?

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298047/2451

Comment: The question is only here.

Answer (score 0):

$SO(4)\sim SU(2)\times SU(2)$

$SO(16)\supset SO(12) \times SU(2)\times SU(2) $

$120=(3,1,1)+(1,3,1)+(2,2,12)+(1,1,66)$

$128=(2,1,32)+(1,2,\bar{32})$